# Inkscape: Convert fill pattern to path

Tags: inkscape, svg

How can I convert a fill pattern, e.g. 'wavy' to a path, so I can edit it as a path, change colour, etc.? I tried Path > Object to Path, it doesn't do anything. I also tried tricks, like export to PDF, reimport through Poppler, again no effect.

[image]

Comment: A sh*tty work around I found for this case which is too complex to redo from scratch, is to export as a high-res PNG (e.g. 1200 dpi), then create a scratch document, import the PNG and vectorise it again (Trace Bitmap). Can't believe such basic functionality is missing in Inkscape…

Comment: I was about to post that. simplify the vectorised paths to smooth them out.

Answer (score 1):

Printing through Microsoft's PDF printer and then reimporting with internal import seems to work for me.

Comment: Works for me also.  I use this method to turn Excel graphs into SVG via PDF.  Graphics convert properly.